# How to prove $B\subset A$ for $A=\{3n; n\in Z^+\}$ and $B=\{9m; m\in Z^+\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been trying to figure how to do the following problem,
Let $A = \{3n : n \in Z^+\}$ and $B = \{9m : m \in Z^+\}$. Prove $B \subset A$.
I see that we need to show that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then all elements of $A$ are in $B$ but $B$ has one element that is not in $A$. I can kind of visualize it but not put it in writing.

Answer (score 3):

See $x\in B\iff \frac{x}{9}\in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

---

Now the proof:

$x\in B\iff \exists m\in \mathbb{Z_+}$ such that $x=9m\implies x=3\times 3m=3n$ where $n=3m\in \mathbb{Z_+}$
$\implies x\in A$.

So we get $\forall x\in B\implies x\in A$.
Hence by definition $B\subseteq A$.

Now $y=3\in A$. But $\frac{y}{9}=\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}\notin \mathbb{Z_+}\implies y \notin B$

So $\exists y\in A$ such that $y \notin B\implies A\neq B$.

Now $B\subseteq A$ and $A\neq B\implies B\subset A$.

Answer (score 0):

All set theory equalities and containments boil down to what you're saying. Show that for any $a\in B$, you also have $a\in A$. For example, $9=9\cdot 1 \in B$ and also $9=3\cdot 2\in A$. The point is, you *know* that every element in $A$ has the form $3m$ for $m$ positive integer and $9m$ for $B$. Use this knowledge.

To show proper containment, find something in $B$ that doesn't belong to $A$.

Comment: So for A we can have 3*1=3 but for be we cant have 3 the lowest we can go is 9, is that what you mean?

Comment: @russiandobby: for strict containment, yes.